# How can I add text over an image in python along with some saturation and brightness adjustments?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm fairly new to coding in python, I was wondering if I could code a script that would allow me to create an image such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzBJ2.jpg)

Is this possible with PIL? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV can do this, refer to its documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html and http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/dc1/tutorial_basic_linear_transform.html

This should get you started:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

cv2.rectangle(img,(512,0),(0,512),(0,255,0),20)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
cv2.putText(img,'HELLO WORLD!',(10,250), font, 4,(255,255,255),2)

image=cv2.cv.fromarray(img)
cv2.cv.SaveImage('pic.jpg', image)
```

Comment: Thanks, could you provide a basic example to get me started? I did mention im fairly new to this.

Comment: I've edited my response to provide you a simple example.